# how to target terms and condition to the another page in magento 2.4.5

Tags: checkout, magento2.4, shipping

i want to use terms and condition as a link of another page on the checkout page in magento 2.4.5-p1, but by default it shows on popup but i have not need this popup.
i want to simple target terms and condition to the another page

Comment: do you to add term and condition in any phtml file?

Comment: no , i have not added anymore thing , im just using by default right now

Comment: do you want to redirect to any other page on term and condition click.

Comment: yes , i want this

Answer (score 0):

To target the terms and conditions page to another page in Magento 2.4.5, you can follow these steps:

Log in to the Magento Admin panel as an administrator.
From the main menu, navigate to **Content > Pages**.
Find the page that you want to link to the terms and conditions page, and click the Edit button for that page.
In the Content section of the page editor, you can use the **WYSIWYG** editor to add a link to the terms and conditions page. To do this, highlight the text that you want to use as the link, and click the Insert Link button.
In the Insert Link window, enter the URL of the terms and conditions page in the Link field. You can find the URL of the terms and conditions page by going to the pages list in the Magento Admin panel, and clicking the Preview button for the terms and conditions page.
When you are finished, click the Save button to save your changes.
Alternatively, you can also use the Link widget in the Magento WYSIWYG editor to add a link to the terms and conditions page. To do this, click the Insert Widget button in the WYSIWYG editor, and select the Link widget from the list of available widgets. Then, enter the URL of the terms and conditions page in the Link field, and click the Insert button to add the widget to the page.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.